# Best practice for services on 5 server farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, services

2 front end servers, 2 Batch/App servers and 1 physical SQL server. We currently do not have a physical load balancer for the environment.

I've read technet for best practices but I was wondering if anybody knew of a resource that would list out the recommended plan for which services should run on which server.

Any help or recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In addition, Microsoft is pushing the Streamlined Topology model, which fits with SharePoint Online - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=37000.

There are no cookie-cutter farms. Farms must be architected to fit your business requirements.

Answer (score 0):

it is open end question, its depend on the what services you need and how much the user load on it.
I would recommend the below topology diagram from MSFT which give you best pictures.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30377
http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/0/7/A07928F6-5153-4E19-B682-B8D28194095A/sps-2013-topology-model.pdf